# How to detect when a WinJS WP8.1 app is resuming after having been tombstoned?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, winjs

In Windows Phone C#/XAML apps, resuming after tombstoning can be detected in the `Application_Activated` method in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
 private void Application_Activated(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (!e.IsApplicationInstancePreserved)
     {
         // we were tombstoned!
     }
 }
```

How can it be detected in a Windows Phone HTML/Javascript app?

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for the [resuming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.webui.webuiapplication.resuming.aspx) event (on WP8.1 you'll also get an [activated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br212679.aspx) event after the resuming event.

```
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", resumingHandler, false);
```

See MSDN's [How to resume an app (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465114.aspx) for more details.